# ImportError: Cannot import name 'gettext'

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, importerror, gettext

I am running a Python3 script within a fresh virtual environment which uses argparse and it has the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bears/generate_package.py", line 1, in <module>
    import argparse
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 93, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext as _, ngettext
ImportError: cannot import name 'gettext'
```

Outside the venv I have uninstalled Python3 and installed it back again, created a fresh venv but it still gives this error. (outside the venv it still doesn't work).

My operating system is a macOS 10.12.13.
By trying `brew install gettext` it says it's already installed.

How exactly do I install gettext?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil [**`gettext`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) is part of python's library.

Comment: Does gettext.py file exist inside /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/?

Comment: @HugoCorrá yes, it does exist.

Comment: You probably have a circular import or one of your files have the same name that a python module. Also, you can try to delete all .pyc files, once you can have some garbage from old installation.

Comment: @HugoCorrá i grepped for *.pyc files all along that path and there's none, nor in my project.

Comment: What would be a "hard reset" way to go? Such as uninstalling all python and all cache for it and everything? Im willing to do that if it fixes it, only that im afraid that i might still leave some cache files or whatever files that would cause the problem to persist, unless I can find the problem in another way.